# Asterisk and voip: which software, which professionals, which facilities

Tags: voip, asterisk

Consider that I don't know anything of asterisk, so one of my questions is who we are the main  actors we know to be aware of in order to start this project.

Basically we want to create a bot (well, asterisk) that is able to call the users phones, have a short conversation with them  where each line pronounced by the system (they'll be audio file) depends on the previous answer of the user (speech recognition, in fact we need to intercept the audio stream and pass it to a 3rd party speech recognition engine) and some logic that can be handled by an external module. Saying that the requirements are up to 200 concurrent conversations, and that the conversations will take place in the USA only, what services should we buy? One VOIP provider, one hosting solution for asterisk. How difficult is it to write the asterisk configuration for such a project?Thank you

Can you help me to separate the actors in such a project: professionals, software, facilities?

Answer (score 1):

1) Dedicated server. But for diallout 200 calls need very hi end server. I think you will got 100 on usual server if got nice 2)

2) Dialling software/core

3) Call managment software - you need write it.

4) voice recognition. If it on your server, i not think it will work with more then 20-30 channels.

5) voip account for dialout(most provider NOT allow do automated dialout for marketing purpose).

most problematic is voice recognition - unlikly you will got quality of recognition if more then yes/no answer. reason: telephony use 8khz sounds, not enought quality for recognition.

Also unlikly you will got 200 channels on one server, so will need clustering=clustering expert or hi cost voip expert.

In general, if you got recognition, all other is doable, cost of development will be 1~100k depend of features.

Comment: I think this answer is bang on. The most expensive parts are going to be your speech recognition software, and the requirements therein. But, 200 concurrent channels is not a joke. That's going to be rather expensive in and of itself. I would consider major carriers for such an endeavor.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this comprehensive answer

Answer (score 1):

I actually would suggest that you use Tropo for this (https://www.tropo.com/).  The rates are reasonable, you can develop in your favorite language, they handle the massive infrastructure you'll require and its got a top-drawer TTS/STT engine built in.